# VIM : Deleting all characters before particular word for all the lines in a file

Tags: vim

I need a vim command for deleting all characters before a particular word for all the lines in a file

Ex:
**Input:**

```
asdfasdfasdfscccHello

qwerqwerHello

24351243vsfgertHello
```

**Output:**

```
Hello

Hello

Hello
```

Comment: if you like a shorter solution, try `:%s/*.\zeHello`

Comment: If deleting until the first `H` works, you could use `dtH` (which means **d**elete un**t**il an H). See: https://superuser.com/questions/1411944/vim-delete-up-until-word-character

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to delete all characters before "Hello", you can do

```
:%s/.*Hello/Hello/
```

Note that `.*` is greedy, i.e. it will eat all occurrences of "Hello" till it finds the last one. If you have a line:

```
abcHellodefHelloghi
```

it will become

```
Helloghi
```

If you want a non-greedy solution, try

```
:%s/.\{-}Hello/Hello
```

Comment: Best solution. Saved my Life

Comment: @pfnuesel How would I do it if instead of hello I wanted a whitespace?

Comment: @MatheusRotta, you just have to add additional `/` to indicate the end of whole command, like so: `:%s/.*Hello/ /` or `:%s/.\{-}Hello/ /`